# socket.io: trying to reference image files in my client file

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

working with socket.io and writing html for the client webpage that displays some image files. The images are saved in a folder that is in the same directory as the html file, so the code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <style>
  #div {margin-top: 250px; }
  #caption {font-size: 20px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <div id = 'div'>
  <center>
    <form action=''>
      <p id='caption'>Choose a pdf to display:</p>
      <div id='picButton'>
        </div>
      <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9d57f22c90ac0c291a7a21a73d10d308/tumblr_oa9bl6o3rF1qgon18o1_540.jpg"></img>
    </form>
    <ul></ul>
  </center>
  </div>
  <script>
    for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
      var path = "/Media/0"+i+".jpg";
      $('#picButton').append($('<img>').attr("src", path));
    }
  </script>
```

However, I keep getting a 404 not found error for the image files. Am I supposed to save the images in another location? I was trying to figure out the correct place to save them based on the fact that the html file is supposed to somehow reference the socket.io.js file with `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, but moving a test image file to the socket.io-client folder inside the node_modules folder still didn't help.

Comment: At the moment, it's going to the root of your web and looking for /Media/01.jpg and /Media/02.jpg from the root. Do they exist there in the Media folder under the root?

Comment: what do you mean by the root of your web?

Comment: Precisely that. The directory that your web lives under in the web server. if you're running this HTML locally on your file system, then it may try to look at the root of the drive that it's running under instead (which may cause cross scripting issues). So, if your web is situation in C:\webs\TestWeb, for instance, then it's looking for the images in C:\webs\TestWeb\Media. If the images are in the same directory as the HTML that requires them, then you could just remove the `/Media/` part above and just refer to the images directly.

Comment: so if I'm just using localhost:7000 as the web should I try to look for that webs folder? the Media folder and the html file are in the same  directory, not the images and the html file.

Comment: Remove the forward slash before Media in that case.

Comment: Hm.. still didnt solve the problem

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your HTML file is in a certain directory. Is there a Media folder in that same directory? And are there 01.jpg and 02.jpg directly inside the Media folder? If so, then "Media/01.jpg" is the correct relative path format to reach them. If not, then describe your resource structure and I'll advise further.

Comment: Yeah, so my entire project folder is C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProject

Comment: Then my javascript server file for socket.io is C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\server.js
My client file's path is C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\client.html
The images are in C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\Media\01.jpg and 02.jpg

Comment: despite this using Media\01.jpg as the path the files still arent found at http://localhost:7000/Media/01.jpg and 02.jpg

Comment: /Media/01.jpg should work given that Media is in the root of your web. And, if your HTML file is in the root, then Media/01.jpg works as well. Provided the file exists, of course. Can you access the image by going to that URL above? Can you post your HTML file code as part of your question?

Comment: And have you tried simply placing an <img> tag directly on the page, in case there's an issue with the JavaScript or HTML structure?

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that your div is enclosing your script tag. Don't do that. Have your script outside that picButton div so that you can sensibly manipulate it via the script.

Comment: Edited my original question with the current html. I placed the image that Im trying to upload on tumblr and displaying that link works.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the img tag you had placed with the tumblr image (downloading it into my Media folder). And I amended the path to remove the forward slash making it a relative path and it works fine.

I also amended all of your HTML attributes to use double quotes and JavaScript to use single quotes.

And I fixed the  tag as it's no longer supported in HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project</title>
        <style>
            #div {margin-top: 250px; }
            #caption {font-size: 20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <div id="div" style="text-align:center;">
            <form action="">
                <p id="caption">Choose a pdf to display:</p>
                <div id="picButton"></div>
            </form>
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    <script>
        for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            var path = 'Media/0' + i + '.jpg';
            $('#picButton').append($('<img>').attr('src', path));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

So long as you have a Media folder in the same directory as this HTML file, and you have 01.jpg and 02.jpg inside that folder, then this will work fine.

Comment: I mean this works fine if you just open the html file by itself, but when I run my server and go to localhost:7000 it's still not able to find the images... thank you for all your help so far, but yeah I have no idea why this isnt working

Comment: It's not an issue with your HTML then. It's a problem with your server config. It could thinking it's performing some kind of cross-origin request. Or it's not handling image mime types or something. Very strange.